# I cannot change page size. Why?

Tags: paper-size, page

I made document a4page size.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,dvipdfmx]{jreport}
```

But I want to change the page size to b5. So I wrote

```
\documentclass[10pt, b5paper,dvipdfmx]{jreport}
```

But the page size does not change. Why??

Comment: Try with package `geometry`, if it is compatible with the `jreport` class.

Comment: I tried. But the text is forced out. Why?

Comment: it seems that  `jreport` not support `b5paper` option or you have in preamble some settings, which override this options.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know this class. Just in case: did you type specifically `\geometry{b5paper}`? Maybe type it with `AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: I wrote \usepackage[b5paper]{geometry}

Comment: Add `[showframe]` to check.

Comment: What is showframe? How should I type?

Answer (score 6):

I suppose your MWE is something like

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,dvipdfmx]{jreport}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

and typeset this using pLaTeX and dvipdfmx, which indeed produces an A4-sized PDF. The reason for this is that the `b5paper` option just tells `jreport` to lay out the content in a B5-sized domain but is not related to the actual page size of the output. In addition to this, DVI has no concept of output page size and therefore dvipdfmx assumes the output page size to be its default value (i.e., A4) when converting the source DVI to PDF.

You have basically three options to set the output page size identical to the layout page size.

## Use dvipdfmx's `-p papersize` option

If you typeset the MWE above with

```
platex mwe.tex
dvipdfmx -p b5 mwe.dvi
```

you will get a B5-sized PDF.

## Use `geometry`'s `pass` option

The `geometry` package is usually used to set margins, but it only sets the output page size same as the layout page size if it is loaded with `pass` option.

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,dvipdfmx]{jreport}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

will produce a B5-sized PDF without specifying the `-p` option in dvipdfmx. Note that you need to add `dvipdfm` (not `dvipdfmx`) to the `geometry` package's option if you use v5.7 or earlier.

## Use `bxpapersize` package

Since `bxpapersize` is a rather new package, it might not be installed in your TeX distribution. This package offers many features about setting the page size, but loading the package is enough in your use case.

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,dvipdfmx]{jreport}
\usepackage{bxpapersize}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

will produce a B5-sized PDF without specifying the `-p` option in dvipdfmx.